# How to get name to refer to property rather than class in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, properties

Compare the following sets of VB.NET classes:

```
Public Class MyProperties
    Private Shared m_customer As Customer
    Public Shared Property Customer() As Customer
        ' getter and setter code 
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Public Field1 As String
End Class

Public Class MyOtherClass
     Sub Proc1
          Debug.WriteLine(Customer.Field1)  ' this does not compile
     End Sub
End Class

-----------------------------------------

Public Class Customer
    Public Field1 As String
End Class

Public Class MyOtherClass
    Private Shared m_customer As Customer
    Public Shared Property Customer() As Customer
        ' getter and setter code 
    End Property
    Sub Proc1       
        Debug.WriteLine(Customer.Field1)  ' this compiles
    End Sub
End Class
```

What can be done to get the top segment to compile?

Could [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hya04w5b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) help?

Answer (score 1):

In the second set of code Customer refers to the Customer *property* of the *current* class (same as `Me.Customer`). You can then access the `Field1` property of the `Customer` property through the **instance** `m_customer` (although this compiles it will thrown an exception at runtime when you try to access the property Customer because you have not have not set a reference to an object using the `new` keyword)

In the top segment the current class does not contain a property called Customer so the compiler will look for objects outside the current class. It then finds a *class* called `Customer`. It can't use the `Field1` property in this case because `Field1` is a non-shared member. If you made `Field` `shared` this would compile.

So to conclude you either need to make a property shared **or** access a property through and instance of the class

Either:

```
Public Class Customer
    Public Shared Field1 As String
End Class

Public Class MyOtherClass
    Sub Proc1
        Debug.Writeline(Customer.Field1)
    End SUb
End Class
```

Or:

```
Public Class Customer
    Public Field1 As String
End Class

Public Class MyOtherClass
    Sub Proc1
        Dim myCust as New Customer
        Debug.Writeline(myCust.Field1)
    End SUb
End Class
```